# how to get json data with curl and php from another domain?

Tags: php, javascript, xml, curl, jsonp

i am triong to do a request to a page and get back some results using curl.

with javascript i could use `$.getJSON` like so:

```
$.getJSON('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=fuzzy%20monkey&v=1.0&callback=?', function(response) {
    console.log(response.responseData);
});
```

but in case javascript is not enables i would like to use CURL. im just not sure how.

also i don't necessarily need the response to be json, xml can be ok also

any ideas?
Thanks

edit: also i don't really want to use `file_get_contents()` but pure curl

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Comment: Please go through this link http://themekraft.com/getting-json-data-with-php-curl/

Comment: Also, it's entirely up to the host (Google in this case) whether the data return will be json, xml, etc. You can't control that unless they provide a means to do so through the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns JSON data from the URL you specified. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php).

```
<?php
        // create curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=fuzzy%20monkey&v=1.0");

        //return the transfer as a string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // $output contains the output string
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        // close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);     
?>
```

It’s entirely up to the host (Google in this case) whether the data returned will be JSON, XML, HTML, etc. You can’t control that unless they provide a means to do so through the API.

[mangobug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952787/mangobug)’s link to [Getting jSON Data with PHP (curl method)](http://themekraft.com/blog/getting-json-data-with-php-curl/) shows you how to send and receive JSON data and how to handle authentication, when necessary.